# SMBD encounters error

Tags: smb

I was running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS for the longest time, then suddenly, after restarting my Ubuntu box, file sharing stopped. I uninstall, re-install, stop and start the service remotely and from the PC itself, but it didn't work. I can connect both Ubuntu Boxes with each other, but not on windows environment! What do I need to do?